# ReactJS is Giving me unreachable code when I'm passing truthness test

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create truthness check in my component to render other components but it is giving me unreachable code error

I dont know how to fix it or where to start

Please help me to solve this issue,
Thanks in advance

```
       return (
  checkCommentAuthor() ? (
        <IsCommentAuthor/>
    ) : (
            <IsNotCommentAuthor/>
        ) :
```

After this everything is unreachable

```
(
                    <div id="card" className="card">
                        <div id="postButtons" className="buttons">
                            <button onClick={() => history.push("/homepage")}>Home</button>
                            <button onClick={() => history.push("/profile")}>My Profile</button>
                            <button onClick={() => LogOut()}>Log Out</button>
                        </div>
                        <div className="posts">
                            <p>
                                Author :
                                {grabUsernameFromLocation()}
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                Title :
                                {grabTitleFromLocation()}
                            </p>
    
                            <p>
                                Description :
                                {grabDescriptionFromLocation()}
                            </p>
    
                            <div>
                                <ul>
                                    {
                                        comments.map((items: any) => {
                                            return (
                                                <p
                                                    key={uuidv4()}
                                                >Comment :
                                                    {items.comment}
                                                </p>
                                            );
                                        })}
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div className="comments">
                                <input ref={commentRef} placeholder={'Write Comment'}/>
                                <button onClick={() => {
                                    addComment(grabIdFromLocation())
                                }}>Add Comment
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        )
    )
    }
```

Comment: Is `<IsCommentAuthor>` and `<IsNotCommentAuthor>` supposed to be render **next to** the card?

Comment: No they are supposed to render if function gives true or false

Comment: Yes, but when should the card be rendered? There seems to right now be a ternary operator (`? :`) but with an additional `:` at the end.